# Why IE doesn't accept brackets when we call a function

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I don't know why I have an function like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSomeEnvValue() {
        myLoadStatus = true;
        myColor = 'black';
    }
    window.onload = setSomeEnvValue();
</script>
```

I don't know why IE show error at:

```
window.onload = setSomeEnvValue();
```

When I change this code to:

```
window.onload = setSomeEnvValue;
```

It makes me crazy. If `setSomeEnvValue()` has some arguments like `setSomeEnvValue(myVar1, myVar2)`, how can I call it when using it in IE?

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, IE has the correct implementation.

When you set a callback (or event handler), such as `window.onload`, you're basically telling the browser that the function that you're giving it should be executed when that event is triggered.

By writing `window.onload = setSomeEnvValue();`, you're saying that the *return value* of setSomeEnvValue should be called whenever the `window.onload` event is triggered. Of course, this *may* be possible if your function returns a closure, but I'm going to assume that's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

What `window.onload = setSomeEnvValue();` means is to run `setSomeEnvValue()` *now* and assign its *result* to `window.onload`.  What you need is to assign the function itself to `window.onload`, so that the browser can run it later.

If you want `window.onload` to call a function with some arguments that you know in advance, make a new function (with no arguments) that calls the other function with the desired arguments, and assign *that* to `window.onload`.

```
function myOnload() {
  setSomeEnvValue(myVar1, myVar2);
}

window.onload = myOnload;
```

or even

```
window.onload = function() { setSomeEnvValue(myVar1, myVar2); }
```